# XCode Organizer console doen't show logs from the device, even though I have restarted the Xcode

Tags: xcode, ipod-touch

1. XCode Organizer console doen't show logs from the device, even though I have restarted the Xcode.
2. Is there other ways to get the device log except XCode Organizer console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't gotten XCode to start showing logs (it has only shown one new log in the past 4 months). But to answer your second question, device logs are copied to `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/` (on the computer, not on the device).